# OppenId connect configuration over Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

There some Micro that are backed by Zuul gateway and all of them are secured by Spring Security OAuth2. The scenario is:

1- The Zuul gateway as OAuth2 client.

2- All backed application are as OAuth2 Resource Server.

3- One application is running as OAuth2 Authorization Server(UAA).

The flow of OAuth2 is `Authorization code` flow. All Resource Server due to get the user info as `Pricipal` calls the endpoint of Authorization Server like this:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9191/uaa/user
```

Every thing is working correctly as expected.

It is necessary to mention, all application are run by Spring Boot

I want to use Jwt, in order to that I will able to extract claims as user-info instead of calling the endpoint of Authorization Server. So I was googling and find `openid connect approach` but I did not find suitable configuration of openid connect over Spring Security OAuth2.

There are two problems:

1- The openid connect is suitable for my problem? if yes, is there a link to help,

2- If not, which technology is suitable for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to clarify the difference between [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).
Reading each RFC is your safest bet, but here is an overview.

**OAuth 2.0** is an authorization framework / protocol.
The end goal of your OAuth 2.0 authorization server is to deliver Access Tokens that you can use to secure your applications. The Access Tokens' goal is only to tell the resource server whether or not a client is allowed to access something, it does not have to include information about a user (but it can). OAuth 2.0 does not make any assumptions about the token format or how to validate tokens.

**OpenID Connect** builds on top of OAuth 2.0 to provide authentication. Along with the access token, the Identity Provider a.k.a. IdP (an identity-enabled OAuth 2.0 authorization server) can provide both an Access Token and ID Token.
The ID Token contains identity information about the user in a standard format (JWT).
OpenID Connect is built for Single-Sign-On (SSO) and applications that need user details/profile (UI in general).

**JWT** is a token format, you can use it for both authorization and authentication.
ID Tokens have to be JWTs, while Access Tokens can be JWT or opaque (random string).
The advantage of JWT is that resource servers only need the signing key to validate tokens. It's the most popular solution these days, and it's a good fit for what you want to achieve (HTTP API security).
Opaque tokens can be seen as more secure (no user information included) but it takes some out of band process to validate : calling an endpoint on the authorization server, sharing a database...

**TL;DR** : if your use case is just HTTP API security, you only need OAuth 2.0, not necessarily OpenID Connect. OAuth 2.0 with Access Tokens in JWT format is pretty convenient, and Spring Security offers good support out of the box. Authorization Servers usually include user info such as username and eventually permissions, so you don't have to look it up from every service.

All managed identity solutions (such as Okta, Auth0, AWS Cognito) implement both OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect so you don't have to choose. Same for RedHat's Keycloak if you want to install your authorization server yourself.
Beware that Spring Security's authorization server only implements OAuth 2.0 (both opaque and JWT tokens). The project is in maintenance mode.

Here is an example of JWT payload in an Access Token coming from AWS Cognito :

```json
{
  "sub": "806b6ec5-6e12-4933-915c-6bd489464a36",
  "cognito:groups": [
    "admin",
    "whatever"
  ],
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_hLzeyVm80",
  "version": 2,
  "client_id": "6jfufigqn4j14hrim4gj76mkjc",
  "event_id": "c074951c-4244-4011-8ef9-449f7552eab1",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin phone openid whatever_you_want",
  "auth_time": 1563965719,
  "exp": 1563969319,
  "iat": 1563965719,
  "jti": "e751e0ef-aff4-4197-bf73-b8ef898ba3fc",
  "username": "806b6ec5-6e12-4933-915c-6bd489464a36"
}
```

The interesting bits are :

- `expiry` : the token's expiry, only field validated by Spring Security (along with the signature)
- `username` : beware that this field is optional (tokens can be delivered to a client app without involving a user through the client credentials grant)
- `scope` : permissions granted to the client application
- `cognito:groups` : a custom claim containing the user's permissions for Role Based Access Control, you can map it to Spring Security authorities -- non standard

Useful : [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) to create and decode JWTs.